# XSLT matching empty nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-stylesheet

I have an XML structure like the following:

```
<Root>
  <!-- ...other stuff -->
  <Events>
    <Event date="0000-00-00">Event Description etc...</Event>
    <Event date="0000-00-00">Event Description etc...</Event>
    <Event date="0000-00-00">Event Description etc...</Event>
  </Events>
  <!-- ...other stuff -->
</Root>
```

Then I have XSLT in the Stylesheet like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="Events" select="/Root/Events/Event" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <!-- Stuff -->    
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$Events" />
  <!-- Stuff -->    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Event">
  <!-- Regular Event Template Transformation here -->
</xsl:template>    

<!-- ERROR HAPPENS HERE -->
<xsl:template match="not(node())">
  <p class="message">There are currently no upcoming events</p>
</xsl:template>
```

What I WANT to do is have two templates, one which only shows when there are no events. I KNOW i can use XSLT with `<xsl:choose>` and `<xsl:when>` tests to do a count of elements and just call the right template like I would do in procedural languages, but I'm trying to learn how to do this with template processing.

The error I'm getting is : 
   **Expected end of the expression, found '('. not -->(<-- node())**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`not(node())` is not a valid XSLT pattern, try this:

```
<xsl:template match="Event">
  <!-- Regular Event Template Transformation here -->
</xsl:template>    

<xsl:template match="Events[not(Event)]">
  <p class="message">There are currently no upcoming events</p>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The first template will match **Event** nodes with (any) child nodes. The second is the opposite. I don't think it solves OP's question.

Comment: @Dimitre Don't think is the most precise and correct. If OP does not change how templates are applied (as shown in my answer) the second template will never be executed.

Comment: @_empo: @Max_Toro has provided a complete solution -- the OP should just use it (such as copy and paste).

Comment: For clarity, to anyone trying to do the same thing, this DOES only work when I'm using `/Root/Events` in my `$Events` variable and not `/Root/Events/Event` as my Question stated. So, I changed it. As a side note, in my case, my `Events` node is actually `<in:result name="GetEvents">` so I needed to change the 1st template to : `<xsl:template match="in:result[@name='GetEvents' and not(Event)]">` to make it work. And it works. ^_^ Thank-you.

Comment: This is cool! I'm using a slightly different version as a fall-back for unrecognised nodes, whereby anything with children (select="*") is rendered as a div block and any leaf node (select="*[not(*)"] is rendered as a key=value...

Answer (score 3):

This might work better

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(node())]">
  <!-- ... -->
```

See also this answer here: [XSLT To remove empty nodes and nodes with -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404491/xslt-to-remove-empty-nodes-and-nodes-with-1#4405192)

Comment: This works, but just curious... as I understand it, the star represents a set of `Event` right? So is this saying match any `Event` with no nodes or "The Set" if it has no nodes?

Comment: Hmm, actually thinking of it again, I'm surprised it does work... I just intended to correct your syntax, not the semantics

Comment: This is a match of any element (can be **Root**, **Events**, **Event**) which does not have a child node (element or text). It **partially** solves OP's question and casually.

Comment: I see. So, it's anything without a node. It COULD work... but I believe not in my specific case... as the `Events` node will have attribute nodes.

Answer (score 2):

### New answer

Reading your question thoroughly, I realize that my last solutions leads you nowhere. My new answer follows:

Since you need to know whether are any elements inside `Events` you need to change the `/` matching template:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <!-- Stuff -->    
   <xsl:apply-templates select="/Root/Events" />
   <!-- Stuff -->    
</xsl:template>
```

Now a template that only matches a populate `Events` along with the required `Event` template:

```
<xsl:template="Events[count(child::Event) &gt; 0]">
   <xsl:apply-template select='./Event'/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template="Event">
    <!-- some stuff -->
</xsl:template>
```

Now the template that matches an empty `Events`:

```
<xsl:template="Events[count(child::Event) = 0]">
   <p class="message">There are currently no upcoming events</p>
</xsl:template>
```

### Old answer

Try with:

```
<!-- This matches every node with an empty string repr. Maybe you want
     to replace "self::*" to avoid attributes, etc." -->
<xsl:template match="*[string-length(self::*) = 0]">
</xsl:template>
```

Details:

If I recall correctly, in XPath/XSL '*' matches any type of node, i.e., text nodes, element nodes, comment nodes, attribute nodes, etc... So in a given context `*[string-length(self::*) = 0]` may match with a attribute; for instance, you may have a `select='@*'` somewhere else. So this template may be applied to attributes as well as elements.

If you're sure it won't match any attribute, you may leave it as it is. However, I like that my code expresses the right ideas. So, if this template your be applied to Event elements only, I would change the match for something like:

```
<xsl:template match="Event[string-length(self::*) = 0]">
</xsl:template>
```

Taking a peek at the XSLT spec at http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt, it seems that * matches only elements. However, I would test it.

Comment: Can you help explain what it means about avoiding attributes? Does this mean if there's an `Event` with no content inside, it will also be matched?

Comment: Updating the answer with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Your processor throws an error because your matching pattern results in a boolean value and not in a node.

---

Try this transform out (which keeps the required variable):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="Events" select="/Root/Events/Event"/>

    <xsl:template match="Root">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$Events
            | Events[not(Event)]"/>  
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Event">
        <p class="message">There is an event</p>
    </xsl:template>    

    <xsl:template match="Events">
        <p class="message">There are currently no upcoming events</p>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied on your input, produces:

```
<p class="message">There is an event</p>
<p class="message">There is an event</p>
<p class="message">There is an event</p>
```

When applied on input without events, such as:

```
<Root>
  <Events/>
</Root>
```

produces:

```
<p class="message">There are currently no upcoming events</p>
```

Comment: I've tried this... and I've found that you can't use this with the $Events variable e.g. `match="$Events[not(Event)]"` My structure needs to use a variable, unfortunately... the example I gave was simplified to reflect the structure I'm getting back.

Comment: Check now my answer. I've edited the templates so that the variable is used. Hope it's what you are searching for, otherwise I think I need much clearer information about your requirements.

Comment: I think it was my misunderstanding of how the "match" parameter works. i was trying to do this: `<xsl:template match="$Events[not(Event)]">` but it didn't like the `$`

Comment: Yes, I realize that... I had changed the value of the variable. I guess what I was hoping with in the beginning was to match "null" but it didn't make much sense when I thought of it.

Comment: Variables are allowed in template match only in XSLT 2.0

Comment: It's still not clear what is the answer which worked for you. If no one here, you can add an answer yourself (and accept it after a while). I'm curious..